# git recognizes me from the command line but not from cron

Tags: cron, git

When I do this:

```
cd /home/erelsgl/git/erel-sites;  git commit -m "test"
```

I get correctly:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But, when I put the same line in the crontab of my account, I see in the logfile:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'erelsgl@erelsgl-computer')
```

I put "whoami" in the crontab and got the same answer as outside ("erelsgl").

I also tried to put the recommended "git config --global" commands inside the crontab (I already ran them successfully outside the crontab) but this did not help.

What should I do to commit from crontab?

Comment: Are you putting these commands in the cron table for your account, or root's, or some other user's?  Presuming that it's in your cron table, try prefixing the command with `export GIT_DIR=/home/erelsgl; `.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I get an error "fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/erelsg‌​l".    I also tried "export GIT_DIR=/home/erelsg‌​l/git", "export GIT_DIR=/home/erelsg‌​l/git/erel-sites" and   "export GIT_DIR=/home/erelsg‌​l/git/erel-sites/.git", and got similar errors.

Comment: Does it work if you just set them explicitly? I mean like this: `cd /home/erelsgl/git/erel-sites;  git commit -c user.email=you@email.com -c user.name=erelsgl -m "test"`

Comment: @terdon I am not sure what it does, but I get an error "fatal: Option -m cannot be combined with -c/-C/-F/--fixup.".

Comment: How are you adding this to cron? Via `/etc/crontab` or `crontab -e`? If via `/etc/crontab`, you probably also need to set `$HOME`.

Answer (score 2):

git needs to find `user.email` and `user.name` in one of its config files or in environment variables. You have more options to make git get these values. Obviusly git does not use some of the config files when called from crontab.

I would recommend you to choose from two options:

1.
Put `user.email` and `user.name` into the repository's config with commands

```
git config user.email "you@example.com"
git config user.name "Your Name"
```

You should be in the repository when doing this. In that way, the repository config file `.git/config` will have the values set and the commit should work from crontab. You can check with

```
cat .git/config
```

2.
Set the environment variables to help git get the missing values. In that case I would run the commands like this

```
cd /home/erelsgl/git/erel-sites; GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Your Name" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="you@example.com" git commit -m "test"
```

I think the variables GIT_AUTHOR_NAME and GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL should also work.

I have found this information on the following pages:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config
- https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/
- https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the best solution in a multi-user system.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `--global`, try `--system`

```
sudo git config --system user.email "you@example.com"
sudo git config --system user.name "Your Name"
```

Comment: But your answer still uses `--global`?

Comment: Obviously I'd get something wrong. Actually replace `--global` by `--system` in the long snippet. I don't have edit privileges for my answer.

Comment: You do have edit privileges for your own answer.

Comment: I didn't see the link at first, maybe because it was just posted. Now it's fixed.

Comment: This works! But it must be run with "sudo"

Comment: It doesn't matter if it has to run with sudo. When you put the user.name and user.email into system config file, you don't need to run these command any more. However, this sets the user.name and user.email for the whole system. I guess you don't have other users on the computer that would have problems with these system settings.

Comment: This is the simplest solution in my system, where I am the only user.